# How to return the latest record to each person ID in SQL

Tags: sql, greatest-n-per-group

I am trying to return the latest record to each recordId in the database.
I have a table which stores notifications, each notification has its own id but they are associated with one personId.
However this person Id can have multiple notifications. What I am trying to do is to retrieve just the last notification to each personId on the notification table.

For instance, I can have many personIds, each personId can have many notifications but each personId should return just the last notification created (PS I save a timestamp for each new notification)

What I came up with so far is:

```
   SELECT *
   FROM Notification
   WHERE notificationEndDate <= '20151101'
   AND
   person_id IN
   (
    SELECT MAX(notificationEndDate )
    FROM Notification
   )
```

The query runs but looks like I lost it somewhere.
Can anyone suggest how can I achieve it please?

Comment: Welcome to SO.  Please show sample table data and expected output.

Comment: Which DBMS are you using?

Comment: In addition to OldProgrammer's comment, I would also like to know exactly what database are you using? This can affect the SQL as differences databases have different syntax and commands.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Return a row if there exists no later row with same personId.

```
SELECT *
FROM TPER_VISA t1
WHERE per_visa_ed <= '20151101'
AND NOT EXISTS (select 1 from TPER_VISA t2
                where t2.personId = t1.personId
                  and t2.per_visa_ed <= '20151101'
                  and t2.per_visa_ed > t1.per_visa_ed)
ORDER BY per_visa_ed
```

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
WITH CTE1 AS(
SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY person_id ORDER BY per_visa_ed   
DESC) AS Row_COUNT
FROM TPER_VISA
)
SELECT * FROM CTE1 WHERE Row_COUNT = 1
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply, however it still returning all the notifications to a person. I am going to edit the post to be more clear. Thank you